# How does the chain rule apply here?

Tags: logic

I have this example from my book (Discrete Mathematics, Goodaire et al p32) on logical arguments, and I have difficulty seeing how the first 2 premises of $$p \to q \\ 
(\lnot r) \to p \\
 \lnot q \\ 
---- \\
r
$$
imply the truth $(\lnot r) \to q$ by the chain rule?

The chain rule states $$p \to q \\ q\to r \\ ---- \\p\to r $$

My attempt at reasoning: $p \to q$ and $\lnot r \to p$, $\lnot q$ are all true. Thus, q is false, and p is false. $\lnot r \to p$ is true, so $\lnot r$ is false. So, r is true. Thus $\lnot r \to q$ is true.

The reasoning arrived at the correct conclusion however, I don't see how the chain rule applies.

Also, does anyone know how to format a line instead of the dotted lines before the conclusion?

Comment: If you wish to apply the chain rule: from $p\to q$ and $(\neg r)\to p$, you may get their contrapositives $(\neg q)\to (\neg p)$ and $(\neg p)\to r$.

Comment: Or you may apply the chain rule to get $(\neg r)\to q$, then modus tollens.

Comment: Note: the text is *Discrete* Mathematics, not [*Discreet*](https://www.dictionary.com/e/discreet-vs-discrete/) Mathematics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think contrapositives work here.

$p\to q \iff \lnot q \to \lnot p$

$\lnot r \to p \iff \lnot p \to r$

So $\lnot q \to \lnot p \to r$ by the chain rule.